# AJAX request not returning hidden HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Using **`$.ajax`**, I am simply trying to return the `id` value of a lone `span` element from another page with `console.log`. The problem seems to be that the element is not visible; inspector has the `span` HTML greyed out (*element has no dimensions and likely no `display`*).

The code below is attempting to first confirm the element can be found on that page:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: extLnk,
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data){
            console.log( $(data).filter("span").length );
        }
 });
```

Console output is always 0, as if the element can't be found. How can I find the element's `id`? Thanks!

Comment: Does the element you're trying to target exist on the page when it first loads, or is it added later via JS?

Comment: What is the runtime contents of `data`?  This seems to have less to do with AJAX itself and more to do with whatever the server is returning.  You can include an example of the value of `data` as a hard-coded literal in the example.

Comment: console your `data` first and check it has `span` or not?

Comment: @Alok Mali - The HTML that is returned via 'data' doesn't show the span element, only it's 'div' parent.

Comment: @GuagLan — If it isn't there at all, then of course it doesn't show up.

Comment: @Quentin - What would be the reason 'data' would omit the span, but not the parent 'div'? The page has ample time to load all elements.

Comment: @GuagLan — Because there is no span in the html of the URL in the first place. (Maybe if some JS ran it would be added. That JS is not running because you aren't loading the page in the normal way).

Comment: *"The page has ample time to load all elements"* - this statement is nonsensical.  Either they're loaded or they're not loaded - it has nothing to do with how long they take.  This implies that you **know** the page loads extra data after the initial load and you're expecting that extra data to be loaded even though you're only getting the initial load.

Comment: @freedomn-m - No, it's not clear if the page is loading more data after the initial load, but if the element isn't being returned then I assumed it's due to the request completing before everything could be fully loaded on that page, but as I'm a beginner with $.ajax I'm only guessing.

Comment: @Quentin - Is it possible to retrieve the element with $.ajax at this point if the problem actually is the script(s) not being run? Is there another way?

Comment: With `$.ajax` you're not "loading a page" - you're retrieving data, in this case you're getting the source of the page.  There's no "before everything could be fully loaded *on the page*" as there is no "page".

Comment: Try this.  Open the browser, go to the network tab, make sure it's recording and clear.  Hit control-F5.  See all the different entries?  Your $.ajax call is getting the *first* and *just the first*, the one with type=document.  All the other ones like script/stylesheet/image are not loaded.  Nothing is run, just some text is retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

You've misidentified the problem.

If you don't do any filtering, you will get a length of *one* which is whatever the top-level element in `data` is.

`filter` just filters the top-level matches, it doesn't search for descendants. You need `find` for that.

```js
const data = `
<div>
   <span></span>
   <span></span>
</div>
`

console.log( $(data).filter("span").length ); // 0 because it is a div

console.log( $(data).filter("div").length ); // 1 because it still a div

console.log( $(data).find("span").length ); // 2 because there are 2 spans inside the div
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've tried both 'find' and 'filter' and they both return the same result. I can only return '1' for the parent 'div' the span is in, not the span itself.

Comment: @GuagLan — Then maybe the span isn't in the data at all.

Comment: Yes, you're right. 'data' returns the parent 'div' but omits the 'span' element for some reason. I believed it was due to the element not having dimensions.

Comment: HTML is just text, dimensions are part of the *representation* of that HTML - you're just getting the text, not how it's rendered.